# How to extract multiple urls from String?

Tags: shell, shell-script, string, string-manipulation

I have a string like below

> https://website.com/BTAE/2015/BTAE assignment jan 15.pdf²0ÔË'\„QI„"ÙP¾^ŒŸZ‡@Æ*]Ü.^‚vðƒ€Ù¾»Æš©Šñ‘€é•
>   ªÂIR#œÉgÉÛ^gMdÉ%9¬e˜Hžôb¿'0<î©˜ô ?lþzk…éÃÄórÈ;EW¦K³1…²ì¶ZFžŠÒô*ÄÖ\ã]»’{ÂMçíÂ¦DêiÁßÅÁ½ :n„q¹1ÙDRó=±Â{EDûEb@N5tÍ›,§ààká@¡;(º\0AÇSª¾Q¾ÒÉœí[‘rú€"?í®§ä‡ÕYÈ<¸^WÐPÁ’4îÖƒÔ'…÷f·qhttps://webservices.ignou.ac.in/assignments/BTAE/2015/BTAE assignment jan 15.pdf
>   https://website.com/BTAE/2015/base-005.pdf

**I need to get urls of all pdf, doc files from the string.**

I am new to SHELL SCRIPT and searched a lot but didn't got any success.

Comment: Which OS and shell?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 14.04.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
grep --only-matching -P "http.*?\.(pdf|doc)" myfile.pdf
```

The output for your sample is:

```
https://website.com/BTAE/2015/BTAE assignment jan 15.pdf
https://webservices.ignou.ac.in/assignments/BTAE/2015/BTAE assignment jan 15.pdf
https://website.com/BTAE/2015/base-005.pdf
```

Comment: there is one more problem with script => https://website.com/bschindi11.htm https://website.com/bschindi11.htm#aoc https://website.com/bschindi11.htm#ec https://website.com/bschindi11.htm#fc https://website.com /CHEMISTRY/2007/CHE_01.doc . It is giving me this url.

Comment: @AabirHussain That is because the URL is not prefixed with `http`

Comment: Sorry for wrong comment but
there is one more problem with script => https://website.com/bschindi11.htm https://website.com/bschindi11.htm#aoc https://website.com/bschindi11.htm#ec https://website.com/bschindi11.htm#fc https://website.com /CHEMISTRY/2007/CHE_01.doc . It is giving me this url

Comment: @AabirHussain Enclose your whole block in backticks (`)